# Why PlotStyle affects style of mesh in 3D?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

In the documentation of `PlotStyle` we can read:

> PlotStyle->None specifies that the main objects in a plot should not
> be drawn explicitly, though mesh and filling are not affected.

But as can be seen `PlotStyle -> None` and `PlotStyle -> Transparent` affects style of mesh.

Is this a bug?

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> None]
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Transparent]
```

[image]

Comment: yes, looks like a bug.

Comment: a simpler example: `Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> 10, MeshStyle -> Red]` versus  `Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Transparent, Mesh -> 10,  MeshStyle -> Red]` or `Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0], Mesh -> 10,  MeshStyle -> Red]`. In the last two cases, mesh style directives are completely ignored and `Opacity[0]` is used for styling mesh points.

Comment: Only v11.3 can reproduct this bug. 12.2, 12.3,13.3.1,14.0 work fine.